# CSRF Setting issues when creating Facebook Page Tab for a Codeiginter Page

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, csrf

I created a facebook page tab, 
and tried loading a page generated by the codeIgniter 2.2.1 
(CentOS 5.5, PHP 5.3.3).

`$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`

The following errors occurred.

> Error: An Error Was Encountered - The action you have requested is not
>   allowed.

Please see the screenshot
Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2LlP.png)

Comment: FB it's doing some POST requests while it's loading your app and doesn't know how you handle your app, or better - doesn't know the CSRF token to pass this to your app. Try to disable the CSRF and if it's working you may need to modify this (disable on load and enable again when your app is loaded inside the FB iframe)

Answer (score 0):

I think, This is not CSRF Error. This error is your page request not found. so, please check your path which have you call. and check controller name with "First Letter" Capital. and check load view path.
For more information. [MORE](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)

ThankYou.

Answer (score 0):

FB it's passing the `signed_request` while it's loading your app and doesn't know how you handle your app, or better - doesn't know the CSRF token to pass this back to your app.

Try to disable the CSRF and if it's working you may need to modify this.
I don't have access on a CodeIgniter setup right now, but something like this should work:

```
if (!$_POST['signed_request']) 
{
    $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
}
```

*That's just an example and you can modify it according your app needs/security measures.